# How can I share folder with password on the cloud

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing, cloud-storage, sharing

Is there any possible way to share a folder on the internet in such a way that people can open it with a password without the need for me to enter their emails (e.g., like dropbox). I do not have the emails of the people I want to share the folder with. I do not want to share the folder to public. Dropbox and gmail drive requries me to enter emails for those who can read the folder content but I do not have their emails. Can you suggest any method if there is any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DropBox, Box.com and many other file-sharing services allow you to right-click on a file or folder and to obtain a link that anyone can use, though it's not password protected. Just password-protect files (e.g. using LibreOffice or MS Word protection) or zip the folder and password protect it before uploading. Most zip utilities, such as 7-Zip and PeaZip, have password options on saving.

Comment: That's tue. Typo coected.